# return "this" in C++?

Tags: c++, return, this

In Java you can simply `return this` to get the current object. How do you do this in C++?

Java:

```
class MyClass {

    MyClass example() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should test it using (almost) the same code and see what's the result? Also, your method is a void method in code above, so you probably don't want to return anything anyways.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Well, first off, you can't return anything from a `void`-returning function.

There are three ways to return something which provides access to the current object: by pointer, by reference, and by value.

```
class myclass {
public:
   // Return by pointer needs const and non-const versions
         myclass* ReturnPointerToCurrentObject()       { return this; }
   const myclass* ReturnPointerToCurrentObject() const { return this; }

   // Return by reference needs const and non-const versions
         myclass& ReturnReferenceToCurrentObject()       { return *this; }
   const myclass& ReturnReferenceToCurrentObject() const { return *this; }

   // Return by value only needs one version.
   myclass ReturnCopyOfCurrentObject() const { return *this; }
};
```

As indicated, each of the three ways returns the current object in slightly different form. Which one you use depends upon which form you need.

Comment: Don't forget the const versions.

Comment: Hi, where can I read about `need const and not const versions`. I can't to understand this. If method changes not class members, I write const version, else - write not const. Why need I both?

Comment: @vp_arth you cannot initialise a `myclass*` from `this` in a const-qualified member function: `myclass* ReturnPointerToCurrentObject() const { return this; }` is ill-formed, even though the *body* of the method does not modify anything in `myclass`

Comment: What's the difference between these three?

Answer (score 12):

One of the main advantages of *return by reference* in classes is the ability to 
easily chain functions.

Suppose that your member function is to multiply a particular member of your class.
If you make the header and source files to keep the information of the class and the definition of the member function separately, then,
the header file  `myclass.h` would be:

```
#ifndef myclass_h
#define myclass_h
class myclass{
  public:
    int member1_;
    double member2_;

    myclass (){
       member1_ = 1;
       member2_ = 2.0;
    }     

    myclass& MULT(int scalar);
    myclass* MULTP(double scalar);
};
#endif
```

and the source file: `myclass.cpp` would be:

```
myclass& myclass::MULT(int scalar){
      member1_ *= scalar;
      return *this; 
}
myclass* myclass::MULTP(double scalar){
      member2_ *= scalar;
      return this; 
}
```

If you initialize an object called `obj`, the default constructor above sets `member1_` equal to 1:
Then in your main function, you can do chains such as:

```
myclass obj;
obj.MULT(2).MULT(4);
```

Then `member1_` would now be 8. Of course, the idea might be to chain different functions, 
and alter different members.

In the case you are using the *return by pointer*, the first call uses the object, 
and any subsequent call will treat the previous result as a pointer, thus

```
obj.MULTP(2.0)->MULTP(3.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the return type is `void`, i.e.: you declare that you don't return anything. Change it to `myclass*` to return `this` change to `myclass &` to return reference to the class through `*this`.