# Return value vs pointer vs reference in C++

Tags: c++

I saw this question on StackOverflow:

[return "this" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919330)

And a question came to my mind - what's the difference between these three?

```cpp
class myclass {
public:
   // Return by pointer needs const and non-const versions
         myclass* ReturnPointerToCurrentObject()       { return this; }
   const myclass* ReturnPointerToCurrentObject() const { return this; }

   // Return by reference needs const and non-const versions
         myclass& ReturnReferenceToCurrentObject()       { return *this; }
   const myclass& ReturnReferenceToCurrentObject() const { return *this; }

   // Return by value only needs one version.
   myclass ReturnCopyOfCurrentObject() const { return *this; }
};
```

Comment: Start by explaining the difference between returning by value and returning by reference. What crucial thing happens when we return by value that doesn't happen when we return by reference or pointer?

Comment: The return type is the difference.

Comment: Look at the name you gave your return-by-value function.  The secret, which Silvio is referring to, is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the following:

```
int i = 10;
int* ptr = &i;
int& ref = i;
int copy = i;
```

If you understand the differences between the last three lines, you can extend that understanding to the member functions in your posted code. If you don't understand the differences, it will be best to learn these basic concepts from [a good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).